# Efficient way of searching a table with multiple order requirements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a requirement to search a customers table and return a list of potential matches in the following order:

*(or return no matches if the criteria does not match)*

1. First Row: Exact matches for First Name, Last Name and Email Address
2. Next Rows: Exact matches for First Name and Last Name
3. Next Rows: Exact matches for Last Name and Email Address
4. Next Rows: Exact Matches on Email Address only
5. Next Rows: Exact Matches on First Name

My customers table looks something like the following:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | first_name | last_name | email_address | dob | created_at | updated_at|
| ___|____________|___________|_______________|_____|____________|___________|
|  1 |   John     |   Wick    |   jw@aol.com  | ... |  .......   | ........  |
| .. |  ........  | ......... | ............. | ... |  .......   | ........  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The payload that is passed and is used for searching comes in the following format:

```
payload: {
    first_name: 'john',
    last_name: 'smith',
    email_address: 'd@live.com'
}
```

The only way i can think to achieve the following is to perform each query individually, union them in the required order and remove duplicates. Something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
    WHERE first_name = payload.first_name 
    AND last_name = payload.last_name
    AND email_address = payload.email_address
UNION
SELECT * FROM customers 
    WHERE first_name = payload.first_name 
    AND last_name = payload.last_name
UNION
....
```

I'm not convinced that this is the most efficient way to achieve this as it will perform five select queries for each search operation. Is there a better way of expressing what i'm trying to achieve that is more performant or concise or is this a solid approach?

Comment: Yes, it's more efficient to run 5 separate queries for different searches (if you have proper indexes for each search), and then `UNION` them. You'll need to add a `score` to each query in order to sort the resulting rows.

Comment: what you are building is an OR for all three conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a single query like this I think, the duplicates would already be removed

```
SELECT customers.*, 
  CASE 
  WHEN (
    first_name = payload.first_name 
     AND last_name = payload.last_name
     AND email_address = payload.email_address
   ) THEN 1
   WHEN (
    first_name = payload.first_name 
     AND last_name = payload.last_name
   ) THEN 2
   # ... all your other criteria
   END AS criteriaId
FROM customers 
    WHERE 
    (
      first_name = payload.first_name 
      AND last_name = payload.last_name
      AND email_address = payload.email_address
    )
    OR
    (
     first_name = payload.first_name 
     AND last_name = payload.last_name
    )
   # ... all your other criteria
```